# Swipe event preventing navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery

My mobile page displays an image that is larger than the screen, so the user needs to swipe to the right to see the entire thing (as intended).  I want to put in an event that hides the navigation div when the user swipes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).on('pageinit', '#main_page', function() {
        $('#container').on("swipe", function () {
            $('#arrow').remove();
        });
      });
</script>


<body>
<div data-role="page" id='main_page'>
<div id="arrow">
    <div>Swipe</div>
    <img src="rt_arrow.png"></img>
</div>
<div id="container" style="width:100%; height:340px;">
</div>
</div>

</body>
```

This works, except swiping no longer moves the image/view.  I'm testing on an iphone, although I want it to work cross-platform.

EDIT:

I tested by just having this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).on('pageinit', '#main_page', function() {

      });
</script>
```

And the image still won't navigate around, so the problem isn't in the remove vs hide or relevant to the divs themselves.

Comment: Is the image in #container DIV ? Did you try a `.hide()` rather than `.remove()` ?

Comment: The image is positioned with fixed positioning to be on top of the container div, but the image div is not actually inside the container.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are removing the element from DOM with

$('#arrow').remove().

What you need to do is

$('#arrow').hide()

Comment: Makes no difference--same result.  Note that I've attached the swipe to the container div, not the arrow.

Answer (score 0):

I had this in the head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

Removing the first link fixed the problem.  If anyone would like to explain why as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: If instead this question should be closed or the title amended to better reflect the action problem, have at it.